# shiny: difference between sidebarPanel sidebarLayout

Tags: shiny, sidebar

I've been trying to figure out, when to use sidebarLayout and when not. I am stuck and maybe someone here can explain it to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically with `sidebarLayout` you specify the layout of your page, which means that your page will be splitted in two; a `sidebarPanel` and a `mainPanel`.

Inside `sidebarLayout` you use `sidebarPanel` to specify how the side panel of your page will look like. In brief first you use `sidebarLayout` and after that `sidebarPanel`.

The example below is taken from [shiny's](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/sidebarLayout.html) documentation. It illustrates what was stated above. You can use it if you want your page to look like the App below.

```
library(shiny)
# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar with a slider input
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("obs",
                  "Number of observations:",
                  min = 0,
                  max = 1000,
                  value = 500)
    ),

    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(rnorm(input$obs))
  })
}

# Complete app with UI and server components
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: alright. I've been using sidebarPanel without using sidabarLayout a couple of times before and just cannot see the difference between using sidebarPanel inside  sidebarLayout or just by itself

Comment: Could you please share a bit of code where you 're using just sidebarPanel?

Comment: If I uncomment sidebarLayout in your example, there is no difference I can see in the output. So that's why I am wondering why I should use it.

Comment: sidebarLayout is not commented in my example.

Comment: I meant comment, sorry

Comment: They look the same that's true but if you check under the hood they're not. If you right click on the page where the App is launched and inspect the source code you will notice the difference between the two versions(hashed and unhashed). I don't consider myself a HTML expert so I don't know what kind of problems you might encounter if you skip sidebarLayout. In my opinion follow the official shiny documentation and always use sidebarLayout.